# This.controls.find()[0] Error: Index was outside the bound of array

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I have a question to ask, I am trying to save the dynamically created `rich textboxes` text into `sql database` using `This.controls.find()[0]`. But there is an error which return `Index was outside the bounds of the array`. I don't know what I should set for the array since i don't have any. Error happen on `testing = (RichTextBox)this.Controls.Find("testing" + a.ToString(), true)[0];` Please help me. Thank you in advance. Codes are below:

```
   public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    RichTextBox testing = new RichTextBox();
    RichTextBox lol = new RichTextBox();
    ComboBox haha = new ComboBox();
    int i = 0;

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int rows = this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount + 1;
        tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
        testing = new RichTextBox();
        testing.Name ="testing"+ i.ToString();
        testing.Width = 227;
        testing.Height = 96;
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(testing, 0, rows + 1);

        lol = new RichTextBox();
        lol.Name = "lol" + i.ToString();
        lol.Width = 227;
        lol.Height = 96;
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lol, 1, rows + 1);

        haha = new ComboBox();
        haha.Name = "haha" + i.ToString();
        haha.Items.Insert(0, "Visibility of system status");
        haha.Items.Insert(1, "Match between system and the real world");
        haha.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        haha.Width = 224;
        haha.Height = 21;
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(haha, 2, rows + 1);

        tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount++;
        i++;
        tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout();
    }


    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a <= i; a++)
        {
            string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HeuristicDatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

            SqlConnection myconnection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

            String strCommandText = "INSERT Form(Location,Violation,Recommendation)"
               + " VALUES(@Location,@Violation,@Recommendation)";
            SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myconnection);

            testing = (RichTextBox)this.Controls.Find("testing" + a.ToString(), true)[0];
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Location", testing.Text);

            lol = (RichTextBox)this.Controls.Find("lol" + a.ToString(), true)[0];
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Violation", lol.Text);

            haha = (ComboBox)this.Controls.Find("haha" + a.ToString(), true)[0];
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Recommendation", haha.SelectedItem);

            myconnection.Open();

            Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myconnection.Close();
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Data added into database!");
    }
```

EDIT: Now there isn't the error index was outside the bound of array but there is a problem when the data are added into the database, the 2nd data will never be recorded into the database, what is the cause of this problem?? Please help. codes below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    RichTextBox testing = new RichTextBox();
    RichTextBox lol = new RichTextBox();
    ComboBox haha = new ComboBox();
    int i = 0;

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int rows = this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount + 1;
        tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
        testing = new RichTextBox();
        testing.Name ="testing"+ i.ToString();
        testing.Width = 227;
        testing.Height = 96;
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(testing, 0, rows + 1);

        lol = new RichTextBox();
        lol.Name = "lol" + i.ToString();
        lol.Width = 227;
        lol.Height = 96;
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lol, 1, rows + 1);

        haha = new ComboBox();
        haha.Name = "haha" + i.ToString();
        haha.Items.Insert(0, "Visibility of system status");
        haha.Items.Insert(1, "Match between system and the real world");
        haha.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        haha.Width = 224;
        haha.Height = 21;
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(haha, 2, rows + 1);

        tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount++;
        tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout();

        i++;
    }


    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HeuristicDatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection myconnection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

        String strCommandText = "INSERT Form(Location,Violation,Recommendation)"
           + " VALUES(@Location,@Violation,@Recommendation)";
        SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myconnection);

        myconnection.Open();

        for (int a = 0; a < i; a++)
        {
            Cmd.Parameters.Clear();

            testing = (RichTextBox)this.Controls.Find("testing" + a.ToString(), true)[0];
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", testing.Text);

            lol = (RichTextBox)this.Controls.Find("lol" + a.ToString(), true)[0];
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Violation", lol.Text);

            haha = (ComboBox)this.Controls.Find("haha" + a.ToString(), true)[0];
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Recommendation", haha.SelectedItem);

            Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        myconnection.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Data added into database!");
    }
```

SOLUTION:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
       public Form1()
         {
            InitializeComponent();
         }

    RichTextBox testing = new RichTextBox();
    RichTextBox lol = new RichTextBox();
    ComboBox haha = new ComboBox();
    int i = 1;

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int rows = this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount + 1;
        tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
        testing = new RichTextBox();
        testing.Name ="testing"+ i.ToString();
        testing.Width = 227;
        testing.Height = 96;
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(testing, 0, rows + 1);

        lol = new RichTextBox();
        lol.Name = "lol" + i.ToString();
        lol.Width = 227;
        lol.Height = 96;
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lol, 1, rows + 1);

        haha = new ComboBox();
        haha.Name = "haha" + i.ToString();
        haha.Items.Insert(0, "Visibility of system status");
        haha.Items.Insert(1, "Match between system and the real world");
        haha.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        haha.Width = 224;
        haha.Height = 21;
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(haha, 2, rows + 1);

        tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount++;
        tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout();

        i++;
    }


    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HeuristicDatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection myconnection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

        String strCommandText = "INSERT Form(Location,Violation,Recommendation)"
           + " VALUES(@Location,@Violation,@Recommendation)";
        SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myconnection);

        myconnection.Open();

        //This are richtextboxes which are created at design time.
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", testing0.Text);
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", lol0.Text);
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", haha0.SelectedItem);

        for (int a = 0; a < i; a++)
        {
            Cmd.Parameters.Clear();

            //This are to retrieve texts from the textboxes that are created during runtime
            //And add it into the database.
            testing = (RichTextBox)this.Controls.Find("testing" + a.ToString(), true)[0];
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", testing.Text);

            lol = (RichTextBox)this.Controls.Find("lol" + a.ToString(), true)[0];
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Violation", lol.Text);

            haha = (ComboBox)this.Controls.Find("haha" + a.ToString(), true)[0];
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Recommendation", haha.SelectedItem);

            Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        myconnection.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Data added into database!");
    }
```

}

Comment: On which line exactly? Debug your code and you can easily find the error and fix it.

Comment: okay the error happen on testing = (RichTextBox)this.Controls.Find("testing" + a.ToString(), true)[0]; sorry didn't say where the error was. I edited the question alr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your for loop should be like

```
for (int a = 0; a < i; a++)
```

Also, as a suggestion, your btnSave_Click should have the following changes

- Declare, open and close the connection outside the loop (only once)
- As you are using parameterized command, declare the command once, and in each loop, add parameters and then execute

  ```
  private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HeuristicDatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

      SqlConnection myconnection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

      String strCommandText = "INSERT Form(Location,Violation,Recommendation)"
         + " VALUES(@Location,@Violation,@Recommendation)";
      SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myconnection);

      myconnection.Open();

      for (int a = 0; a <= i; a++)
      {
          Cmd.Parameters.Clear();    // clear the parameters so that previous values are cleared

          testing = (RichTextBox)this.Controls.Find("testing" + a.ToString(), true)[0];
          Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Location", testing.Text);

          lol = (RichTextBox)this.Controls.Find("lol" + a.ToString(), true)[0];
          Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Violation", lol.Text);

          haha = (ComboBox)this.Controls.Find("haha" + a.ToString(), true)[0];
          Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Recommendation", haha.SelectedItem);

          Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
      myconnection.Close();
  }
  ```

Comment: Okay it wasn't the last data that was missing but the 2nd data.

Comment: I am getting all the records and I didn't find a reason as why the any data should get missed :(

Comment: Well i can't go chat not enough reputation LOL and they call me to go to chat ~.~

Comment: Alright i still have static richtextbox named testing0. I used the ++ to add like auto increment. Will this affect the result?

Comment: Well i tried uploading an image of my ui but apparently i don't have enough reputation too T.T

Comment: try closing Visual Studio and restarting

Comment: Tried and nope still missing the 2nd data. T.T

Comment: but still, the problem is still there. Is it possible that somehow you can share you code with me?

Comment: UPDATE: So i tried saving 1 record only and it doesn't work, most probably it is because a<i and if they both are 0 it will jump over the for loop that's why the data is not saved.

Comment: Okay i solved it myself already. I add the static rich text boxes statically. Then the dynamic ones are in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `a <= i` should be `a < i` .

Comment: I tried. But the database always save 1 less than what i entered.
But yeah it solved the problem about having the out of bound error.